# How to formulate this expression

Tags: matlab, function, sum, formula

I am new to MATLAB and I want to formulate the following lease square expression in Matlab. I have some codes that I am typing here. But the optimization problem solution seems not to be correct. Does anyone has an idea why?

First, I want to solve the heat equation
$$T_t(x,t) = - L_x . T(x,t) + F(x,t)$$
where L_x is Laplacian matrix of the graph.
then find y from the following least square.

$$ \min_y \sum_{j} \sum_{i} (\hat{T}_j(t_i) - T_j(t_i, y))^2$$

Thanks in advance!!

Here is my code:

```
%++++++++++++++++ main ++++++++++++++++++++
% incidence matrix for original graph
C_hat = [ 1 -1  0  0  0  0;...
         0  1 -1  0  0 -1;...
         0  0  0  0 -1  1;...
         0  0  0  1  1  0;...
        -1  0  1 -1  0  0];
% initial temperature for each vertex in original graph
  T_hat_0 = [0 7 1 9 4];
 [M_bar,n,m_bar,T_hat_heat,T_hat_temp] = simulate_temp(T_hat_0,C_hat);
 C = [ 1  1 -1 -1  0  0  0  0  0  0;...
   0 -1  0  0  1 -1  1  0  0  0;...
   0  0  1  0  0  1  0 -1 -1  0;...
   0  0  0  1  0  0 -1  0  1 -1;...
  -1  0  0  0 -1  0  0  1  0  1];
   %
   % initial temperature for each vertex in original graph
    T_0 = [0 7 1 9 4];
   %
   % initial temperature simulation
    [l,n,m,T_heat,T_temp] = simulate_temp(T_0,C);
   %
   % bounds for variables
    lb = zeros(m,1);
    ub = ones(m,1);
    %
   % initial edge weights
    w0 = ones(m,1);
   % optimization problem
   %  w = fmincon(@fun, w0, [], [], [], [], lb, ub);

     %++++++++++++++++++++ function++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   function [i,n,m,T_heat,T_temp] = simulate_temp(T,C)
   %
     % initial conditions
      delta_t = 0.1; 
      M = 20; %% number of time steps
      t = 1; 
      [n,m] = size(C);
      I = eye(n); 
      L_w = C * C';
      T_ini = T';
      Temp = zeros(n,1);
      % Computing Temperature
      %
      for i=1:M
          K = 2*I + L_w  * delta_t;
          H = 2*I - L_w  * delta_t;
          %
          if i == 1
              T_heat = (K \ H) * T_ini;
              %
              t = t + delta_t;
          else
              T_heat = (K \ H) * Temp;
              %
              t = t + delta_t;
          end
              % replacing column of T_final with each node temperature in each
              % iteration. It adds one column to the matrix in each step
              T_temp(:,i) = T_heat;
              %
              Temp = T_heat;
      end  
   end


     %++++++++++++++++++ function+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
   function w_i = fun(w);
   %
     for r=1:n
         for s=1:M_bar
             w_i = (T_hat_temp(r,s) - T_temp(r,s)).^2;
         end
     end
```

Comment: what is Fj? and Ej? do i an dj go to infinity or the sum has a stop?

Comment: you could probably write this vectorized with `meshgrid`, but we need more info to give helpful answers.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I have added more explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give a more  clear answer, I need more information about what form you have the functions F_j and E_j in.

I've assumed that you feed each F_j a value, x_i, and get back a number.  I've also assumed that you feed E_j a value x_i, and another value (or vector) y, and get back a value.

I've also assumed that by 'i' and 'j' you mean the indices of the columns and rows respectively, and that they're finite.

All I can suggest without knowing more info is to do this:

1. Pre-calculate the values of the functions F_j for each x_i, to give a matrix F - where element F(i,j) gives you the value F_j(x_i).
2. Do the same thing for E_j, giving a matrix E - where E(i,j) corresponds to E_j(x_i,y).
3. Perform **(F-E).^2** to subtract each element of F and E, then square them element-wise.
4. Take **sum(** (F-E).^2**, 2)**. sum(M,2) will sum across index i of matrix M, returning a column vector.
5. Finally, take **sum(** sum( (F-E).^2, 2)**, 1)** to sum across index j, the columns, this will finally give you a scalar.

Comment: I have edited now with more explanation and codes along with it.